# sql server sum union

Tags: sql-server-2008, sum, union

```
select '' as xxx,pawn.propawn_price as yyy from product_pawn pawn
inner join product_history history on history.propawn_id = pawn.propawn_id
and history.prohistory_status = '0'
union 
select pawn.propawn_price * 8/100 as xxx,'' as yyy from product_pawn pawn
inner join product_history history on history.propawn_id = pawn.propawn_id
and history.prohistory_status = '1'
union
select pawn.propawn_price + pawn.propawn_price * 8/100 as xxx,'' as yyy 
from product_pawn pawn
inner join product_history history on history.propawn_id = pawn.propawn_id
and history.prohistory_status = '2'
union
select prosell_pricesell as xxx,'' as yyy from product_sell
where prosell_status = '5'
```

result

xxx   yyy

0 --- 900

0 --- 800

700 --- 0

0 --- 100

500 --- 0

i want sum xxx and sum yyy

1200  1800

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Can try like this...

```
  SELECT Sum(xxx) as xxx,Sum(yyy) as yyy from (
    select '' as xxx,pawn.propawn_price as yyy from product_pawn pawn
    inner join product_history history on history.propawn_id = pawn.propawn_id
    and history.prohistory_status = '0'
    union 
    select pawn.propawn_price * 8/100 as xxx,'' as yyy from product_pawn pawn
    inner join product_history history on history.propawn_id = pawn.propawn_id
    and history.prohistory_status = '1'
    union
    select pawn.propawn_price + pawn.propawn_price * 8/100 as xxx,'' as yyy 
    from product_pawn pawn
    inner join product_history history on history.propawn_id = pawn.propawn_id
    and history.prohistory_status = '2'
    union
    select prosell_pricesell as xxx,'' as yyy from product_sell
    where prosell_status = '5') t
```

Comment: @Harajukuzz welcome dont forget to accept it as answer if it helped u